# How can I hide the app name?

Tags: android

I wanna hide the app_name in my application. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I hope you aren't making something sneaky.  Like a virus.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide the app_name in my application"?

Comment: Guys? Why so many negative votes? It was a genuine question - the guy wanted to hide the activity name.

Comment: -1 since no efforts made to search answer

Comment: Ofcourse I tried to figure it out by myself but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this onCreate method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the manifest file in the activity you want to hide it, add this:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"